# Ruby: Idiomatic way to compare every index of array to all other indexes of the same array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say I have an array `arr = [7,0,4,-7]` and I'd like to get the pair of indexes `[i, i2]` where `arr[i] + arr[i2] == 0`. In the example, the answer would be `[0, 3]`. What would be the idiomatic and efficient way to do so?

Here's the best I've gotten so far. I'm sure it's not the best way to do it. Previously I was using two while loops but I feel like this isn't any better.

```
> nums = [7,0,4,-7]

> nums.each_index do |n1|
    (nums.length).times do |n2|
      return [n1, n2] if nums[n1] + nums[n2] == 0
    end
  end

> [0, 3]
```

Comment: Is answer [1,1] also correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry, I guess I'm still trying to figure out how those features work. Thanks for the tip. I adjusted my selection. Do you have a solution I can compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method requires only a single pass through the array. It returns all pairs of indices of elements of the array that sum to zero.

**Code**

```
def zero_summing_pairs(arr)
  processed = {}
  arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(n,i),pairs|
    processed[-n].each { |j| pairs << [j,i] } if processed.key?(-n)
    (processed[n] ||= []) << i
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
zero_summing_pairs [7,0,4,-7]
  #=> [[0, 3]] 
zero_summing_pairs [7,4,0,7,4,0,-7,-4,-7]
  #=> [[2, 5], [0, 6], [3, 6], [1, 7], [4, 7], [0, 8], [3, 8]]
```

The associated values are as follows.

```
arr = [7,0,4,-7]
zero_summing_pairs(arr).map { |i,j| [arr[i], arr[j]] }
  #=> [[7, -7]] 

arr = [7,4,0,7,4,0,-7,-4,-7]
zero_summing_pairs(arr).map { |i,j| [arr[i], arr[j]] }
  #=> [[0, 0], [7, -7], [7, -7], [4, -4], [4, -4], [7, -7], [7, -7]]
```

**Explanation**

- `pairs` is the array of pairs of indices of values of `arr` that sum to zero. `pairs` is the object that is returned by the method.
- `processed` is a hash with keys equal to the values of `arr` that have been processed by the block. The value of each key `k` is an array of the indices `i` of `arr` that have been processed by the block and for which `arr[i] #=> -n`. I chose a hash structure for fast key lookup.

The line

```
(processed[n] ||= []) << i
```

requires explanation. Firstly, this is shorthand for

```
processed[n] = (processed[n] || []) << i
```

If `processed` has a key `n` (whose value is not `nil`), the value of that key on the right side of the above expression is a non-empty array containing indices `i` for which `arr[i] #=> -n`, so the above expression reduces to

```
processed[n] = processed[n] << i
```

and the index `i` is added to the array. If `processed` does not have a key `n`, `processed[n]` equals `nil`, so the expression becomes

```
processed[n] = (processed[n] || []) << i
             = (nil || []) << i      
             = [] << i
             = [i]
```

In other words, here the value of key `n` is made an empty array and then `i` is appended to that array.

Let's now step through the code for

```
arr = [7,0,4,-7]

processed = {}
enum0 = arr.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [7, 0, 4, -7]:each_with_index>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> [[7, 0], [0, 1], [4, 2], [-7, 3]]
```

Continuing,

```
enum1 = enum0.with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [7, 0, 4, -7]:each_with_index>:with_object([])> 
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[[7, 0], []], [[0, 1], []], [[4, 2], []], [[-7, 3], []]]
```

If you examine the return value for the definition of `enum1`, you will see that it can be thought of as a "compound" enumerator. The empty arrays (corresponding to the block variable `pairs`) will be filled in as the calculations are performed.

The first value of `enum1` is generated and passed to the block, and the three block variables are assigned values using *parallel assignment* (aka *multiple assignment*) and *disambiguation* (aka *decompositon*).

```
(n,i), pairs = enum1.next
      #=> [[7, 0], []] 
n     #=> 7 
i     #=> 0
pairs #=> []
```

As

```
processed.key?(-n)
  #=> processed.key?(-7)
  #=> false
```

the first line of the block is not executed. The second line of the block is

```
(processed[n] ||= []) << i
  #=> processed[n]
  #=> [i]
  #=> [0]
```

so now

```
processed
  #=> {7=>[0], 0=>[1]}
pairs
  #=> []
```

The remaining three elements generated by `enum1` are processed similarly.

```
(n,i), pairs = enum1.next
  #=> [[0, 1], []] 
processed.key?(-n)
  #=> processed.key?(0)
  #=> false 
(processed[n] ||= []) << i
  #=> (processed[0] ||= []) << 1
  #=> [] << 1
  #=> [1]
processed
  #=> {7=>[0], 0=>[1]}
pairs
  #=> []
```

```
(n,i), pairs = enum1.next
  #=> [[4, 2], []] 
processed.key?(-n)
  #=> processed.key?(-4)
  #=> false 
(processed[n] ||= []) << i
  #=> (processed[4] ||= []) << 2
  #=> [] << 2
  #=> [2] 
processed
  #=> {7=>[0], 0=>[1], 4=>[2]} 
pairs
  #=> []
```

```
(n,i), pairs = enum1.next
  #=> [[-7, 3], []] 
processed.key?(-n)
  # processed.key?(7)
  #=> true 
processed[-n].each { |j| pairs << [j,i] }
  # processed[7].each { |j| pairs << [j,3] }
  #=> [0] 
(processed[n] ||= []) << i
  #=> (processed[-7] ||= []) << 3
  #=> [] << 3
  #=> [3] 
processed
  #=> {7=>[0], 0=>[1], 4=>[2], -7=>[3]} 
pairs
  #=> [[0, 3]]
```

Notice that the last value generated by `enum1` is the first to have a match in `processed`, so is treated differently than the previous values in the block calculation. Lastly,

```
(n,i), pairs = enum1.next
  #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end (an exception)
```

causing `pairs` to be returned from the block and therefore from the method.

Comment: It did not find all the zero summing pairs - e.g. [0,8], [4,7]. The solution is not very idiomatic and readable.

Comment: In my second example there are two pairs of `7`'s and `-7`'s. As you see, I paired those at indices `0` and `6` and at indices `3` and `8`. In what is it not idiomatic? As far as readability goes, I don't think an experienced Rubiest will find it difficult to follow. That is not meant as a criticism. When I was newish to Ruby I would have had trouble following this. I will provide an explanation.

Comment: Then there should be 4 combinations of their positions.

Comment: I see, you want all combinations of pairs that sum to zero. I fixed it. Please come back in six months and see how long it takes to figure out the code.

Comment: @kallax, I mixed you up with the OP, which is why my replies to your comments may have seemed a bit odd.

Answer (score 3):

The following code will find you all pairs of elements where the sum is zero.

```
arr = [7,0,4,-7, -4, 5]
zero_sum = arr.combination(2).select { |pair| pair.first + pair.last == 0 }
zero_sum #=> [[7, -7], [4, -4]]
```

You can then find the indexes of these elements this way:

```
zero_sum.map { |pair| [arr.index(pair.first), arr.index(pair.last)] } #=> [[0, 3], [2, 4]]
```

If you need just one pair use method `find` instead of `select`:

```
arr.combination(2)
   .find { |first, last| first + last == 0 } #=> [7, -7]
   .map { |num| arr.index(num) } # =>[0, 3]
```

Comment: Perfect! I was playing around with `combination` but couldn't wrap my head around getting the indexes. It's a very handy method.

Comment: `[7,7,-7,-7].combination(2).select { |pair| pair.first + pair.last == 0 } #=> [[7, -7], [7, -7], [7, -7], [7, -7]]` is fine, but your method for extracting the associated indices doesn't work.

Comment: Good point. You are right. I will not delete the answer, because at least the solution for 1 pair works.

Comment: Why not `arr.each_with_index.combination(2).select { |(n1,i),(n2,j)| n1+n2 == 0 }.map { |(_,i),(_,j)| [i,j] } #=> [[0,3]]`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this, it uses `Array#combination`, approach similar to other answer by @kallax, but works on combinations of indices instead of combination of elements:

```
arr = [7,0,4,-7]
(0...arr.size).to_a.combination(2).select {|i| arr[i.first] + arr[i.last] == 0}
#=> [[0, 3]]
```